# auth.signInwithPopup is not a function firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am using firebase google authentication to authenticate user using goole.

But i am facing an error which is given below....

```
(0, _auth.signInWithPopup) is not a function. (In '(0, _auth.signInWithPopup)(auth, provider)', '(0, _auth.signInWithPopup)' is 
undefined)
```

and unable to fix it.

here is my code ...

**import statements**

```
import {getAuth,GoogleAuthProvider,signInWithPopup} from "firebase/auth"
```

**the function**

```
const googlelogin=async()=>{
        const auth=getAuth()
        const provider=new  GoogleAuthProvider()
        try{
            
            const result=await signInWithPopup(auth,provider)
            // const credentials=GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            // const token=credentials.accessToken
            // const user=result.user
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
        
    }
```

Please tell me how to solve this error...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where have you initialized Firebase?

Comment: Same here. Have you found a way to fix it? It looks like a firebase/auth bug of require cycle.

Answer (score -1):

getAuth() function can not be empty. first you should pass the firebase configurations which are can be found on firebase app -> project settings to the initializeApp() function. then pass the results to the getAuth() function.

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

Comment: `getAuth()` can be empty. In that case, it'll use the default Firebase instance. You must pass in a Firebase app instance to `getAuth()` if you are using multiple Firebase apps and want to use auth of specific one.